# Why is Chrome caching my login page?

Tags: cache, google-chrome, cache-control

Our literacy web site for kids with disabilities is causing some users issues with logging in. You can visit the site at `http://tarheelreader.org/`. If you login at `https://tarheelreader.org/login/`, and then go to the login page again you should see a logout message. But Chrome caches the page and returns the original login page instead. The headers are:

```
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Thu, 26 Jan 2017 22:55:55 GMT
Expires:Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Link:<https://tarheelreader.org/?p=110663>; rel=shortlink
Pragma:no-cache
Server:nginx
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-UA_Compatible:IE=edge,chrome=1
```

Which are about every way I could find to say don't cache this page. But the network tab in the debugger shows the page coming from disk cache. If I disable the cache with the checkbox in the debugger things work as they should.

**Update**
If I set the sandbox version of the site to use HTTPS only the problem goes away. Maybe it is something about the switching from HTTP to HTTPS and back?

Comment: I see the cached response too, not sure why as yet. However, you also have a funny redirect going on... if I try to access `https://tarheelreader.org/login` (as in your link), without a trailing slash, then I get a 302 redirect to the `http://...` URL! Only if you include the trailing slash does it appear to behave correctly.

Comment: Fixed in the post. And thanks for looking. I can enable you to login if you need it.

Answer (score 6):

`no-cache` is not as strong as `no-store`.    [Chrome's documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching#defining_optimal_cache-control_policy) indicates that `no-cache` indicates a re-usable document, while `no-store` indicates that it should *not* be re-used.

[image]

Based on this information, your `Cache-Control` header should simply be:

```
Cache-Control: no-store
```

The extra values in it may be letting Chrome pick and choose which it would like to honor.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The diagram is great. Though I need it to work across all browsers even back to IE6! Schools often give the old computers to the classroom for disabled kids. See my update above. Going https only (which I've been meaning to do) seems to fix it.

Comment: IE6 doesn't know about `no-store`.   You could set a different `Cache-Control` header for IE6 using user-agent sniffing.   Alternately, you could have a separate page for logout, or pass a parameter to your login page (even a dummy parameter).

Comment: You are correct. Changing the Cache-Control to no-store and it works perfectly in Chrome.

Comment: No, I spoke too soon. The change doesn't fix it on Windows 10. Same behavior

Comment: [How to control web page caching, across all browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/how-to-control-web-page-caching-across-all-browsers) seems to recommend only `Cache-Control: no-store, must-revalidate` and old versions of IE use `Pragma: no-cache`  but there is one answer that says when using HTTPS the `pragma` header causes Chrome 28 to fail.   It looks pretty much impossible to satisfy all browsers with a single set of directives.

Comment: FWIW... `Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0` (no `max-age:0`) would seem to be the _default_ header that Apache sends for non-caching resources.